# Stack Overflow Firefox Extension

Tags: support

Recently I created a tiny Firefox extension to get given user reputation of Stack Overflow. But I did that using API version 1.1.

How can I migrate that to 2.1? How to authenticate my application with StackExchange?

When I saw the form to register my extension at https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register It is asking for domain for oAuth. What should I give there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use authentication to simply access a user's reputation with version 2.1 of the Stack Exchange API. The URLs have changed slightly, so instead of this:

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/1

You now do this:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/users/1?site=stackoverflow

The JSON response you will receive is nearly identical (the `reputation` member is still there).

However, you should be aware that with version 2.0 of the API, filters have been introduced. These filters (by default) suppress certain members from the response to conserve bandwidth and (in some cases) cut down on query processing time on the server. You can read more about them [here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters).